# Modifying a subarray selected by two consecutive boolean arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to modify a subset of an array which is selected on by two consecutive boolean arrays. In my use case, I have an image `im`, and I'm pulling out a region of interest `roi` using some condition. With the pixels in the ROI, I'm doing some computations, and derive a sub-region `target`. I now want to apply some transformation to the pixels in `target` in the original image. In code:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(800), np.arange(600))
im = (x + y) / 6 # a test image to work with
# use some arbitrary conditions to illustrate this
roi = (im > 64) & (im < 128)
target = (im[roi] & 0xf) > 0x7
```

Now I want to do something like

```
im[roi][target] = 0
```

but this fails silently because `im[roi]` does not directly reference the original array's elements (unlike a normal slice).

What's a nice clean way to do what I want here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the combined mask like so:

```
roi[roi] = target
im[roi] etc.
```

This overwrites `roi`. If you need to keep it:

```
roit = np.zeros_like(roi)
roit[roi] = target
im[roit] etc.
```

Or use indices:

```
import operator
I, J = map(operator.itemgetter(target), np.where(roi))
im[I, J] etc.
```

Comment: D'oh, of course. Thanks! I had some crazy thing with `np.where` indices ginned up which was super ugly, hence the question. This solution is much saner.